# Sum up member elements' values in a list matching the word from a tuple in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to sum up each element in a list which values can be achieved by matching the words from a list. A tuple containing values of each word and a list have phrases are as below:

```
val_tuple = [('and',3),('cat',2),('dog',3),('only',5),('horse',3),('car',3),...]

word_list = ['cat and dog',
             'only horse',
             'dog and horse',
             'only dog',...]
```

The output should be like this:

```
result = [('cat and dog', 8),
          ('only horse', 8),
          ('dog and horse', 9),
          ('only dog', 8),...]
```

I couldn't figure out a way and stuck with several attempts just to sum up the values in list:

```
for w in word_list:
   for val in val_tuple:
       if val[0] in w:
           sum = val[0]
       sum += sum
```

Comment: convert val_tuple to a dict (`dict(val_tuple)` will do that) then you can directly look up your words

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you better construct a dictionary for your word values:

```
word_values = dict(val_tuple)
```

You can simply use *list comprehension*:

```
result = [(sentence,sum(word_values.get(word,0) for word in sentence.split()))
              for sentence in word_list]
```

The boldface part sums the scores up. So what we do for every `sentence` is that we use `.split()` to obtain the words. Now for each of these words we obtain the `word_values.get(word,0)`: this means we perform a lookup and if the element is *not* found, we assume word value 0. We `sum(..)` over all these values and return a tuple `(sentence,sum(..))` for each of these sentences.

Based on the provided sample data, I obtain:

```
>>> result
[('cat and dog', 8), ('only horse', 8), ('dog and horse', 9), ('only dog', 8)]
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for your delightful solution!! You just saved some of my hair  I've been scratching from falling off!! :)